# Raining octopuses

Tags: earth

I saw an ad on YouTube where it was raining octopuses and I was wondering if it was actually possible.
The link is
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ_blyWcQoQ

Extra points

If this could happen anywhere on the globe

If the laws of physics don't change

The octopuses don't actually have to do anything

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Worldbuilding. We would need a bit of substance to answer your question. What do you mean by raining (like is it a once in a lifetime process? A regular process?). What kind of world is that? Is magic allowed? Etc.

Comment: More ralated to skeptics.se

Comment: Try adblock and don't be bothered by such things unless you were watching that on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (but only for a short amount of time).

News reports about sea-things being taken in precipitation and dumped in a separate area are recorded on the Internet. 
But this can happen only for octopuses who are of the right size, and most of them will be dead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, and has happened [before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals#Explanations). However most of the animals would be dead, and it would be mostly fishes raining down. So this can happen almost anywhere, no change in the Laws of Physics required, and the poor octopuses aren't doing anything (and they can't anyways).

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible but unlikely.

It could rain one or two octopodes by the same mechanics as fish, but as they don't have a tendency to shoal into large groups as fish and sometime frogs will, a large fall of octopodes is highly unlikely.

*<sub>(Octopuses is ok, Octopodes technically correct, Octopi is wrong as they're Greek not Latin, but that's an argument for another SE.)</sub>*

Comment: Yes! Octopodes is the correct plural etymologically speaking. Octopuses is passably OK, considering the word has been naturalised into the English language and this means it can follow conventional English usage.